# Excel Index Match with OR Criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I am trying to set up and index/match but want the MATCH to match on 2 items but 1 of the items can exist in one of 2 columns, so I am trying to basically create an index match where I can use an OR criteria for one of the items.

Here is my sample data, and 4 iterations of the formula I have tried so far. It works but it doesn't so any insight would be appreciated.

[image]

```
=INDEX(D1:D4,MATCH(1,(A11=A1:A4)*(B11=B1:B4)*(B11=C1:C4),0))
=INDEX(D1:D4,MATCH(1,(A11=A1:A4)*((B11=B1:B4)+(B11=C1:C4)),0))
=INDEX(D1:D4,MATCH(1,(A11=A1:A4)*OR((B11=B1:B4),(B11=C1:C4),0)))
=INDEX(D1:D4,SUM((A11=A1:A4)+(B11=B1:B4)+(B11=C1:C4)))
```

Comment: The second option worked for me with **Office 365**: `=INDEX(D1:D4,MATCH(1,(A1:A4=A11)*((B1:B4=B11)+(C1:C4=B11));0))`. Alternatively: `=INDEX(D1:D4,MATCH(1,((A1:A4=A11)*(B1:B4=B11))+((A1:A4=A11)*(C1:C4=B11)),0))`.

Comment: If you use an older version, you will have to enter the formula as matrix formula by pressing <Ctrl><Shift><Return>.

Comment: I tried both formulas and neither one worked. It returned N/A on one where both criteria should have been true

Comment: Which office version are you using?

Comment: Excel 2013. I know I know. It isn't my choice nor is it in my control

Comment: try `=IFERROR(INDEX(D1:D4,MATCH(1,INDEX((A11=A1:A4)*(B11=B1:B4),0,1),0)),"")&IFERROR(INDEX(D1:D4,MATCH(1,INDEX((A11=A1:A4)*(B11=C1:C4),0,1),0)),"")` ref : https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria (the last formula)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it from the LearnExcel reddit

```
=INDEX(A1:D4,MATCH(1,(A1:A4=A11)*IF(((B1:B4=B11)+(C1:C4=B11))>1,1,((B1:B4=B11)+(C1:C4=B11))),0),4)

/u/newunit13
```